# How to specify the quickest movement a human can do based on MTM standards?

Tags: industrial-engineering

I am looking for a benchmark as a reference regarding the human Kinesiology that specifies the quickest movement a human can do on basic everyday movements like computer mouse clicking.
As far as I know, there is an standard called MTM (Measurement Time Methods) in the field of industrial engineering and ergonomics which specifies the required time for each basic movement to be done by human. This MTM standard time is provided on the basis of not putting the human (worker) in an overload or underload working situation. So I assume MTM cannot provide me with the shortest possible duration (time) a basic movement can be performed. Do you have any suggestion in this regard?

Comment: You are looking for "reaction time". Just Google it to get citations. I've built software to test this and anecdotally found about 200 - 250 msec for most people. Some are consistently better at about 160 msec.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that sports science is probably a good place to look for this sort of information as reaction times are critical in many sports, for example the reaction times of sprinters to the starting gun are often quoted.

For very simple operations like a button press then the time taken for the brain to process the stimulus, make a decision and react becomes significant.

It is also reasonable to suppose that there will be a difference between making an expected reaction to a cue and tasks where there is some element of decision making.

Equally the time taken to complete the action will depend on the action itself eg if you are but actual reaction times are typically i the order of a few hundreds ms.

There are also [reaction time testing game](https://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime)s online if you want to try it for yourself.